# Deploying Web Pages along with Restful in Embedded Jetty

Tags: java, server, jetty

How can I deploy web pages along with my Restful Project in Embedded Jetty?

I have already setup my Jetty Project to deploy RESTFUL using embedded jetty.

```
public class App {

private static Server server;

public static void main(String...s) {
    initJetty();
}

private static void initJetty(){
    try {
        URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromPath(System.getProperty("jetty.uri", "http://127.0.0.1:32081")).build();
        server = JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(baseUri, new AppResourceConfig());
        server.start();

    } catch(Exception ex){
        stopJetty();
    }

}

private static void stopJetty() {

    if(server != null){
        try {
            server.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
}


public class AppResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {
private static final String REST_BASE_PACKAGE = "com.dinesh.client.endpoints";

public AppResourceConfig(){
    //Base package suffices as it scans all the subpackages recursively.
    packages(REST_BASE_PACKAGE)
    .register(MultiPartFeature.class)
    .register(MoxyJsonFeature.class);
}
}
```

How can I deploy web pages on the same port using embedded jetty? I want to be able to deploy it using the java -jar command on my terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jetty runner for war/jar/ear

```
java -jar jetty-runner-9.4.0.M1.jar jetty-app/target/jetty-app.war
```

Comment: I wasn't asking the command to deploy the file. I want to know if there is any way in which I can include web pages (html, js, css) in the same project and have them deployed along with my endpoints on the same port.